# Proper filtrify month sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a flirty plugin on my website and it works perfectly except one thing:
I want my month category to filter in the month order instead of alphabetical order. How is it possible to do?

In other words: how can I change the sorting order for the filtrify plugin only for some categories?

Example:
http://test.fantazia-svit.com.ua/tours "Месяц" is the month in russian.

**UPD:**
@Seamus To initialize filtrify, I have this code:

```
$(function() {
    $.filtrify("search", "placeHolder", {
        'close': true,
        'match': true,
        'noresults': "Критериев нет",
        callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {
            $('.ft-label').parent()
                .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
                .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();
        }
    });
});
```

for the data I just show in html:

```
<div  data-Месяц="month1, month2, month3">some data</div>'
```

**UPD**
Since nobody knows the answer, I did it this way:
I just show the data in this format:

```
<div  data-Месяц="01 (month1) 2015, 02 (month2) 2015, 03 (month3) 2015">some data</div>'
```

Comment: Can you post a short sample of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @Seamus To initialize filtrify, I have this code:    `$(function() {
    $.filtrify("search", "placeHolder", {
        'close': true,
        'match': true,
        'noresults': "Критериев нет",
        callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {
            $('.ft-label').parent()
                .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
                .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();

                }
            });
        });` for the data I just show '<div  data-Месяц=\"month1, month2, month3\">some data</div>'

Answer (score 0):

this way, with html comments, you can have dates sorted in the right way

```
<div data-name='<!-- 2018-08-21 --> 21 august 18, 
                <!-- 2018-08-22 --> 22 august 18'>
    some text
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome To The StackOverflow, Can u add some explanations? It will be more helpful